# How to add chrome.windows api to C#?

Tags: c#, windows, api, google-chrome

So I am a newbie to APIs and I have seen google's chrome.windows api https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows and I want to usedit, however there is no installation guide or, anything to go on. How do you setup this API in a C# project in VisualStudio?

Update:
**I want to programmatically get all the open tabs in Chrome across all the windows.**

Comment: That is the API for Chrome extensions written in JavaScript, it is unrelated to the operating system Windows and not usable from C# ... You should add details of what specifically it is you want to achieve.

Comment: @AlexK. I updated the question